# Python simple circular reference not removed by garbage collector

Tags: python, garbage-collection, circular-reference

After noticing that memory was not being freed in a GUI app, I made a simple test:

```
import gc

class Item:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.items = []
        self.parent = parent # If this is commented, the gc works as expected

def create():
    __root = Item()
    for i in range(2000000):
        new = Item(__root)
        __root.items.append(new)

    return __root

def dummy():
    root = create()
    input("In dummy function")

dummy()
input("After dummy function")
gc.collect()
input("After garbage collect")
```

This simple tree structure has a list of items that point to the parent. When the execution reaches the second `input` prompt, I was expecting to see the memory freed, but it's not.

If I manually call `gc.collect()` the memory does get freed. Also, if I remove the reference to the parent, of if I make it a `weakref` then the garbage collector frees the memory automatically without manually calling `gc.collect()`.

Why does this happen? Isn't this how the garbage collector is supposed to work?

---

**UPDATE:**

After some more experiments, I noticed the garbage collector does seem to work...but in a dumb way. It doesn't free the memory, instead it *reserves* it. So when new objects are created, they are using this reserved space without increasing the total memory used.

This is a big issue for me because I have a GUI app with multiple sub windows, each potentially loading up to 1GB of data. When I open a few sub windows simultaneously, almost the entire RAM is used. The huge problem is that after I close the sub windows, the RAM is not freed...it's in this *reserved* state.
Every now and then, upon opening a new sub window, a big portion of this RAM is freed, but overall there is still a huge amount of memory that is not released to the OS.

I don't understand the usefulness of such a garbage collector.

Comment: I don't get it, what isn't working? You say *it is* freed when you call `gc.collect()`?

Comment: I think I understand you now, actually. Anyway, *when* the garbage collector runs is complicated, have you tried playing around with [the threshold](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.set_threshold)? Or setting the debugging flags?

Comment: I haven't tinkered with the garbage collector settings (I will though). My confusion stems from the understanding that I shouldn't have to mess around with the garbage collector since it should do it's job in the background. I added the manual call to gc.collect() just to see if the objects are really garbage.

Comment: The issue is that running the logic to identify circular references can be expensive (particularly if there are many objects in your process) so Python tries to do it only sparing (see https://devguide.python.org/garbage_collector/#identifying-reference-cycles).  My calling `gc.collect()` you are saying "pay that cost now", by using weakref you avoid the cycles and cost all together.

Comment: Garbage collection *within* the Python process is entirely separate from the issue of the OS reclaiming memory previously allocated *to* the process.